# Liouville numbers and continued fractions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, continued-fractions, transcendental-numbers, liouville-numbers

First, let me summarize *continued fractions* and *Liouville numbers*.

---

**Continued fractions.**

We can represent each irrational number as a (simple) continued fraction by $$[a_0;a_1,a_2,\cdots\ ]=a_0+\frac{1}{a_1+\frac{1}{a_2+\frac{1}{\ddots}}}$$
where for natural numbers $i$ we have $a_i\in\mathbb{N}$, and we also have $a_0\in\mathbb{Z}$. Each irrational number has a unique continued fraction and each continued fraction represents a unique irrational number.

---

**Liouville numbers.**

An irrational number $\alpha$ is a Liouville number such that, for each positive integer $n$, there exist integers $p,q$ (where $q$ is nonzero) with $$\left|\alpha-\frac pq\right|<\frac1{q^n}$$
The important thing here is that you can approximate Liouville numbers well, and the side effect is that these numbers are transcendental.

---

Now if we look at the Liouville's constant, that is, $L=0.1100010\ldots$ (where the $i!$-th digit is a $1$ and the others are $0$), then we can write
$$L=[0;9,1,99,1,10,9,999999999999,1,\cdots\ ]$$
The large numbers in the continued fraction make the convergents very close to the actual value, so that the number it represents is in that sense "well approximatable".

---

My question now is, can we bound the numbers in the continued fraction below to be sure that the number it represents is a Liouville number?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Bounding the error.**

The error between a continued fraction $[a_0;a_1,a_2,\ldots]$ and its truncation to the rational number $[a_0;a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n]$ is given by
$$
|[a_0;a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots] - [a_0;a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n]|=\left|\left(a_0+\frac{1}{[a_1;a_2,a_3,\ldots]}\right) - \left(a_0 + \frac{1}{[a_1;a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_n]}\right)\right|=\left|\frac{[a_1;a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_n]-[a_1;a_2,a_3,\ldots]}{[a_1;a_2,a_3,\ldots]\cdot[a_1;a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_n]}\right| \le \frac{\left|[a_1;a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_n]-[a_1;a_2,a_3,\ldots]\right|}{a_1^2},
$$
terminating with $\left|[a_0;a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots] - [a_0;]\right|\le 1/a_1$; by iterating this recursive bound we conclude that
$$
\left|[a_0;a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots] - [a_0;a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n]\right| \le \frac{1}{a_1^2 a_2^2 \cdots a_n^2}\cdot \frac{1}{a_{n+1}}.
$$
Let $D([a_0;a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n])$ be the denominator of the truncation $[a_0;a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n]$ (in lowest terms).  Then we have a Liouville number if for any $\mu > 0$, the inequality
$$
a_{n+1} \ge \frac{D([a_0;a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n])^\mu}{a_1^2 a_2^2 \cdots a_n^2}
$$
holds for some $n$.  To give a more explicit expression, we need to bound the growth of $D$.

---

**Bounding the denominator.**

Let $D(x)$ and $N(x)$ denote the denominator and numerator of a rational number $x$ in lowest terms.  Then
$$
D([a_0;a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_n])=D\left(a_0+\frac{1}{[a_1;a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_n]}\right)\\ =D\left(\frac{1}{[a_1;a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_n]}\right)=N([a_1;a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_n]),
$$
and
$$
N([a_0;a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_n])=N\left(a_0+\frac{1}{[a_1;a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_n]}\right)\\ =N\left(a_0+\frac{D([a_1;a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_n])}{N([a_1;a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_n])}\right) = a_0 N([a_1;a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_n]) + D([a_1;a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_n]) \\ = a_0 D([a_0;a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_n]) + D([a_1;a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_n]).
$$
So
$$
D([a_0;a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n]) = a_1 D([a_1;a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_n]) + D([a_2;a_3,a_4,\ldots,a_n]),
$$
and the recursion terminates with $D([a_0;])=1$ and $D([a_0;a_1])=D(a_0+1/a_1)=a_1$.  Since we have $D([a_0;a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n]) \ge a_1 D([a_1;a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_n])$, we can say that $D([a_1;a_2,a_3\ldots,a_n]) \le \frac{1}{a_1}D([a_0;a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n])$, and so
$$
D([a_0;a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n]) \le \left(a_1 +\frac{1}{a_2}\right) D([a_1;a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_n]) \le (a_1 + 1)D([a_1;a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_n]).
$$
An explicit bound on the size of the denominator is therefore
$$
D([a_0;a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n]) \le (a_1+1)(a_2+1)\cdots(a_n+1).
$$

---

**Conclusion.**

We conclude the following theorem:

> The continued fraction $[a_0;a_1,a_2,\ldots]$ is a Liouville number if, for any $\mu > 0$, there is some index $n$ such that $$a_{n+1} \ge \prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{(a_i + 1)^{\mu}}{a_i^2}.$$

Comment: This is a really nice answer, exactly what I was looking for. I have one question however: should the last equation in "*Bounding the error*" not have a "greater than" ($>$) sign instead of a "greater or equal" ($\geq$) sign? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: It doesn't matter... the definition of a Liouville number is equivalent if $\le$ is used, since $\varepsilon \le q^{-(n+1)} \implies \varepsilon < q^{-n}$.

Comment: Right, of course. Silly of me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: apologies, I'm not great at analysis. I assume there are some unbounded sequences $a_i$ which fail to meet the condition in your conclusion, correct?

Comment: Absolutely; it’s a very strong condition.  It implies that there are terms larger than the product of all the previous terms to *any* fixed power.  No sequence that grows like a power law or even exponentially fast will meet it; there need to be   infinitely many “outlier” terms, with “outlier-ness” going to infinity.