# How fast must a continued-fraction-sequence increase that it is guaranteed to describe a Liouville-number?

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions, transcendental-numbers

A sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3,\cdots$ is given. Let $r$ be the number with continued fraction $[0,a_1,a_2,a_3,\cdots]$

> How fast must the sequence increase that we can be sure that $r$ is a Liouville-number ?

For the definition of a Liouville-number, see here : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LiouvilleNumber.html

Comment: I know that usually it is expected that the efforts are shown, but this time, I do not have any clue how to approach.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1668461/liouville-numbers-and-continued-fractions